# How do I add a new full admin account to SCCM 2007?

Tags: permissions, sccm, microsoft-forefront-2010

I want to install Forefront Endpoint Protection on my SCCM server using a new service account that I just created specifically for this purpose. I'll be using a separate reporting database so I'll need to grant the account rights there too I assume but I can handle the SQl end of it.

I've created the AD account and copied my existing admin permissions in the SCCM console. I also added the account to the local "SMS Admins" group. But I can access "Site Management" with my admin ID. The new service account can not. So I assume there's other differences that may impact my FEP install.

So how do you grant full admin rights in SCCM?